# SMP kernel sees only one CPU (i7-930) with ACPI enabled

Tags: linux, gentoo, smp, acpi

A Gentoo box running a up-to-date SMP kernel sees only one CPU eventhough ACPI is enabled in AmiBIOS. Any ideas why?

```
> uname -a
Linux charlie 3.17.7-gentoo #1 SMP Mon Jan 12 19:31:07 CET 2015 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 930 @ 2.80GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

> cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 26
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU         930  @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 5
microcode   : 0x11
cpu MHz     : 2806.755
cache size  : 8192 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bugs        :
bogomips    : 5613.51
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, ACPI was forced off by Grub.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you actually pointed out what the GRUB setting was and what it should be.